# ld: framework not found Reveal

Tags: ios, xcode6

[image]

I had been search for a while , And I found 
[http://support.revealapp.com/discussions/questions/5703-unable-to-integrate-reveal]

I Followed it , But Still Can't Work , Can SomeBody Help Me Fix It

Comment: your given screen shot is difficult to read... please provide a big image

Comment: sure , I had been upload

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Select your Project in the Project Navigator
- Go to the Build Settings tab
- Type "framework search" in the search bar and locate the spot for Framework Search Path
- Add this location to whatever paths are already there: **/Applications/Reveal.app/Contents/SharedSupport/iOS-Libraries**

You should be able to link just fine

Comment: Thx for the response ,  my problem was I had a wrong path installed in my MAC. Solution was actually the same as you , find the correct path then add on Framework Search Path